# Restrictions on a Matrix-Vector product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, products, vectors

Suppose I have a $m\times n$ matrix $\mathbf M$, and a unit vector $\hat v$, of dimension $n$. What restrictions do I need to apply to $\mathbf M$ so that $\lVert \mathbf M\cdot \hat v\lVert \leq 1$ for any $\hat v$?

Comment: I feel this is the kind of question that *actually* deserves the title of "missing context or details". Not because it is simply missing both context and details, but because including them would genuinely produce more useful answers to the question. It isn't "too broad" in the usual sense, but it is too broad in a particular sense which would be entirely alleviated by a brief explanation of motivation.

Comment: I apologise, but I'm really looking for a general answer to the problem I asked. There really aren't any more details than that. In terms of context, it only relates to the specific problem I'm trying to solve (and not the general answer). The matrix $\mathbf M$ is a Jacobian matrix $J(\vec x)$ taken over another vector $\vec y$. The unit vector $\hat v$ is the unit vector of $\vec y$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as saying that the "operator norm" of $M$ is less than $1$, which is equivalent to the largest singular value of $M$ being $1$.  That is, the largest eigenvalue of $M^*M$ has to be less than one.  What kind of conditions are you looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to understand which conditions/characteristics $\mathbf M$ needs to have in order to respect the inequality above. For example, if it needs to be a symmetric matrix, or a diagonal matrix or things like that.

Comment: According to what I wrote above, it does not need to be symmetric or diagonal or anything like that.  Every matrix has a number $c$ so that $|Mv| \leq c$ for all unit vectors $v$:  this is called the operator norm.  It exists simply because the unit sphere is compact, so the function $v \mapsto |Mv|$ attains a maximum.  The condition I give above says that this number is square root of the largest eigenvalue of $M^*M$.  

If you have a diagonal matrix, then you would need all the entries on the diagonal to be less than or equal to 1 in absolute value.

Comment: If M is symmetric, then by the real spectral theorem M is similar to a diagonal matrix, and you would need this diagonal matrix to have entries on the diagonal less than or equal to 1 in absolute value.

Comment: Thank you. So If I got it right, supposing $\mathbf M$ to be real, the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf M^T\cdot \mathbf M$ has to be less than or equal to 1, am I correct?

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: Well, in absolute value.  An eigenvalue of $-2$ is no good.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Thanks!

Comment: "...Which is equivalent to the largest singular value of M being 1." Do you mean that the largest element ($m_{ij}$) of $\mathbf M$ is equal to one? because this doesn't seem to work. Either that or I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value

Comment: Again, thank you very much.